# How to get dropdown data within NgFor in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, object, drop-down-menu

I'm new to angular and I'm trying to create dropdowns inside of a NgFor.
I get an array of object of all students from an api, in which by clicking individual students I have to generate an array of object of selectedStudents, where it has data like id,name,class etc. where each student will have marks out of 10 for three subjects.I want a drop down to add these marks. What is the best possible way to do this?

My students.component.html:

```
     <div  *ngFor="let student of students" >
            <h1>{{student.name}}<h1>
            <div>Select marks</div>


<mat-form-field >
                      <mat-select [(ngModel)]="this.marksInMaths" (ngModelChange)="onMathsChange($event)"  placeholder="Give Math Marks">
                      <mat-option *ngFor="let number of arrayOfMarks" >{{number}}</mat-option>
                      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field >
                      <mat-select [(ngModel)]="this.marksInEnglish" (ngModelChange)="onEnglishChange($event)" placeholder="Give English marks">
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let number of arrayOfMarks" >{{number}}</mat-option>

                      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field >
                    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="this.marksInScience"  (ngModelChange)="onScienceChange($event)" placeholder="Give Science Marks">
                      <mat-option *ngFor="let number of arrayOfMarks" >{{number}}</mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

How do I retrieve this data in component.ts? I want to create an array of selectedStudents where each student will be an object with id, name from old data and marks with new data? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Store changes from the view to your component's data with `[(ngModel)]="student.marksInMaths" `.

Comment: @JeremyThille Hi thanks for your quick reply. Really appreciated. But I can't do anything on the student object as I have to create a new array of objects. Also, I don't have access to the students array in my component as it was passed by the parent. So I have passed student.marksInMaths in the (ngModelChange)="onMathsChange()"  with other data as arguments. It works for me but is it an acceptable solution?

Comment: If it works, why wouldn't it be an acceptable solution? :)

Comment: @JeremyThille haha that's also true. I was just wondering if it's a 'clean coding method'. Anyways, thanks.